# Passive income for International student

Tags: united-states, stocks, f1-student-visa, passive-income

After working 3 jobs and taking advantage of scholarships, I am seeking advice for earning passive income with F1-visa. It's amazing to be able 'buy' time to spent with the family!!

I am very curious if you can guide me in the right direction to read more about earning passive income for international students. For example, where can I read about investing in stock market as an international student (F1)US visa.

Comment: Why is "international student" important in any way?

Comment: I hope it's not too! EDIT: I believe there are more forms to be filled out IRS because of the visa status

Comment: All forms of passive income are going to require an initial investment of either time, money, or both. Either way, it is going to take a long time before the total passive income will exceed the initial investment (if money) or the money you would have gotten from a straight time-for-money transaction i.e. a job.

Comment: You might want to look for answers about the specific form of passive-incone investment you are looking for. Note, _investment_, you need to put your own money or time or both into anything before it can pay back returns on that investment, and if anyone is telling you otherwise you are being scammed.

Comment: That phrase, "'buy' time to spent with the family!!" sounds like someone is misleading you, intentionally or unintentionally.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how it relates to a F1-Visa. Nestor Ledon say's there aren't any restrictions, so I'm going to agree with him there.

There are a lot of different ways to make passive income. A quick Google search can uncover a lot of different ways. A few of my favorite ideas are...

- Investing in dividend producing stocks
- Rental properties
- Creating a product to sell, such as a book

Passive income takes a lot of work to earn. Be careful to avoid any quick-passive income schemes. Most times, these schemes are ways people make passive income off of you. Start small and grow. It may take years to create a passive sustainable income, but if you're consistent with it, you'll get there!

Good luck!

Comment: Rental properties are certainly not "passive" income. It's a part-time job at least. Neither is writing a book, but maybe your definition of "passive" is different than mine.

Comment: @DStanley Depends on how you set up your rental properties. Hiring a team to manage your properties, then it's passive. I guess you could argue that no passive income is truly passive. All passive income requires some level of maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

There are no legal restrictions in regards to **passive income** for an **F1-visa** holder so long as you report gains to the IRS.

So any passive investment advice should apply to you.